# Draw sample from all groups in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How do I draw a sample (say, 10% randomly or alternatively every nth row) of rows from within each group inside a dataframe ?

e.g. from when grouping by 'name':

```
name    a    b
foo     1    1
foo     4    1
foo     3    3
bar     2    1
bar     3    7
bar     4    3
bar     1    2
```

I want to get something like:

```
name    a    b
foo     4    1
bar     3    7
bar     1    2
```

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to group by your `name` column and then apply `sample` to randomly get samples from the subgroups.

First, let's see the dummy data:

```
print(df)

    name    a   b
0   foo     1   1
1   foo     4   1
2   foo     3   3
3   bar     2   1
4   bar     3   7
5   bar     4   3
6   bar     1   2
```

`fraction` defines the percentage of random sample. It is set to 0.5 here for your small dummy data set:

```
fraction = 0.5
result = df.groupby("name", group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=fraction))

print(result)

    name    a   b
3   bar     2   1
6   bar     1   2
0   foo     1   1
2   foo     3   3
```